# How to make client app gets all table rows in data base from server app through share library interface by .net remoting

Tags: c#, .net, linq, remoting

I have a grid-view in remoting client app, and I need to fill it with remoting linq query result which is on the remoting server app.

I'm using .net remoting with a web form client app, interface class as shared library, a console app as server has linq to sql database (`StudentsDB`).

I tried to identify an array method on the interface and implement it in the server. But I always get an error that Interface.array can't be converted or casted to server.array

Shared library class

```
public interface IMyRemoteStudent
{
     Array getAllStudents();
}
```

Server

```
namespace Server
{
    public class RemoteStudent : MarshalByRefObject, IMyRemoteStudent
    {
        public RemoteStudent()
        {
        }

        public Array getAllStudents()
        {
            var ctx = new LinqDataContext();
            var std = (from ss in ctx.Students
                       select ss).ToArray();

            return std;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                HttpChannel chnl = new HttpChannel(1234);
                ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chnl, false);
                RemoteStudent Obj = new RemoteStudent();
                RemotingServices.Marshal(Obj, "MyRemote.soap");
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
 protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     HttpChannel chnl = new HttpChannel();
     ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chnl, false);

     IMyRemoteStudent ST = (IMyRemoteStudent)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IMyRemoteStudent),
                    "http://localhost:1234/MyRemote.soap");

     Array arr = ST.getAllStudents()
     gridview.datasource = arr;
}
```

All answers online help to share one student object but I need to retrieve all students as `list<>` or as `array[]` or any object type

Comment: Try DataTable dt = ctx.Students.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Why don't you upgrade your technology and move to Web API?